# 2 formularios diferentes com campo select

Tags: javascript, html

Preciso de 2 formulários na mesma página e estou tentando no final criar um campo select para que eu possa escolher entre um ou outro, estou tentando aqui varias maneiras sem sucesso ! por favor ajudem, segue:

```
<div class="module-body" id="div1">
    <section class="docs">
        <form method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal row-fluid">
            <input type="hidden" name="codigoPlanoEscolhido" value="<?=$codigoPlano?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="nomePlanoEscolhido" value="<?=$nomePlano?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="tipoPlanoEscolhido" value="<?=$tipoPlano?>" />


   <input type="text" name="clienteEmail" value="<?php  $telefone = '55' . $cliente->telefones[1]->ddd .       $cliente->telefones[2]->numero;

    echo '(22)'.("******"), substr($telefone, -3).''

      ;?>" class="span3" disabled />
        <br>

            <button name="confirmarPedido" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Confirmar Minha Solicitação Por SMS</button>
        </form>

<div id="div2" class="module-body" style="display:none">
            <form method="post" action="upgrade-3">
                <input type="hidden" name="codigoPlanoEscolhido" value="<?=$codigoPlano?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="nomePlanoEscolhido" value="<?=$nomePlano?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="tipoPlanoEscolhido" value="<?=$tipoPlano?>" />
                <button name="solicitarUpgrade" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Confirmar solicitação por Email</button>
            </form>

            <script>
                function oWhichSubmit(thisSubmit) {
                    var oWhich = thisSubmit.value;
                    if (document.getElementById(oWhich)) {
                        document.getElementById(oWhich).click();
                    }
                }
            </script>

            <select onchange="oWhichSubmit(this)" onkeypress="oWhichSubmit(this)">
                <option value="confirmarPedido"></option>
                <option value="confirmarPedido">Submit1</option>
                <option value="solicitarUpgrade">Submit2</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="confirmarPedido" id="upgrade2" value="confirmarPedido" />

     <?=getClienteEmail($cliente)?>"  class="span3" disabled/><br>
 <button name="solicitarUpgrade"  class="btn btn-primary                        tn-lg">Confirmar solicitação pelo Email</button>
                </form>
          "  class="span3" disabled/>
           <input type="submit" name="solicitarUpgrade"        id="upgrade3" value="solicitarUpgrade" />
            </form>

 <select id="mySelect">
 <option value="div1">div1</option>
<option value="div2">div2</option>
</select>


 <script>

document.getElementById("mySelect").addEventListener("change",       myFunction);
function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
   if(x=="div1"){
    document.getElementById("div1").style.display="block"; 
  document.getElementById("div2").style.display="none"; 
    }else if(x=="div2"){
    document.getElementById("div2").style.display="block"; 
  document.getElementById("div1").style.display="none"; 
    }
}
 </script>
```

preciso que select no final me de a opção de escolher entre um e outro e fazer o submit

Comment: Os dois formulários seriam o `#upgrade2` e `#upgrade-3`? Se sim, são exatamente o mesmo formulário, apenas mudando o texto no botão, então pode ter apenas um formulário e incluir o campo `select` no mesmo.

Comment: entao amigo, sao 2 formularios, no de cima eu faço uma autenticac'ão por SMS ,, no de baixo faço a autenticaçao simples por email, ai quero separar os 2 com select no final e nao to sabendo fazer, editei la

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloque cada formulário dentro de divs diferentes com display none:

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="div1">div1</option>
  <option value="div2">div2</option>
</select>
<div id="div1" style="background:red;height:100px;width:100px;">
  <form></form>
</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none;background:blue;height:100px;width:100px;">
  <form></form>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("mySelect").addEventListener("change", myFunction);
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    if(x=="div1"){
        document.getElementById("div1").style.display="block"; 
      document.getElementById("div2").style.display="none"; 
    }else if(x=="div2"){
        document.getElementById("div2").style.display="block"; 
      document.getElementById("div1").style.display="none"; 
    }
}
```

Fiz esse exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/k8ebn4ja/

Comment: é deu certo, mas no form2 <div id="div2" style="display:none"><form method="post" action="upgrade-3">   ele nao aparece !

Comment: Deixa eu ver como está seu código agora, pq dá forma q está ali em cima a div upgrade3 está dentro da upgrade2, ai se estiver dessa forma não vai aparecer mesmo...

Comment: editei la veja como esta

Comment: Você não está fechando a div1, nem a div2 nem a section. Tente dessa forma: fecha a section  depois a div1 após o </form> e a div2 depois do segundo </form>

Comment: Foi, muito obrigado Jessika, me salvou aqui

Comment: Só pra complementar, eu adicionaria um id a cada form e depois de selecionar o form faria o submit dentro do if: `document.getElementById("form1").submit();`

Comment: Ow adiciona um botão tipo submit dentro de cada form, ai cada botão submit vai executar a action do form que ele pertence.